# Why can't I submit a dynamically created form in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I copied a part of a bigger project i'm working on, I didn't wrote the code so I hope someone could help me find out why sending a post request from js code with this fashion works in IE and doesn't in other browsers.

```
function f() {
    var container = document.createElement("form");
    container.method = "post";
    container.action= "http://localhost:3203/somefile.aspx";
    document.appendChild(container);
    container.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `document.body.appendChild(container)` instead.

Comment: Woow, that totally worked! Thank you very much, I've been trying to find out this for hours.