# Why my dynamic form is not getting submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dynamic form to submit with few input elements, but it does not send a request. I use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check

Here is my code

```
var form_ref = document.createElement("form");
form_ref.id = "viewform";
form_ref.name = "viewform";
form_ref.action = "/csm/showResult.action";
form_ref.method = "post";
form_ref.target = "_self";

var cfgidField = document.createElement("input");
cfgidField.name = "cfgid";
cfgidField.type = "text";
cfgidField.value = configid;
form_ref.appendChild(cfgidField);

var cfgnameField = document.createElement("input");
cfgnameField.name = "cfgname";
cfgnameField.type = "text";
cfgnameField.value = configname;
form_ref.appendChild(cfgnameField);

var cfgdescField = document.createElement("input");
cfgdescField.name = "cfgdesc";
cfgdescField.type = "text";
cfgdescField.value = configdesc;
form_ref.appendChild(cfgdescField);

var cfgenvField = document.createElement("input");
cfgenvField.name = "cfgenv";
cfgenvField.type = "text";
cfgenvField.value = configenv;
form_ref.appendChild(cfgenvField);

var cfgfileField = document.createElement("input");
cfgenvField.name = "cfgfile";
cfgenvField.type = "text";
cfgenvField.value = absolutepath;
form_ref.appendChild(cfgfileField);

var cfgdateField = document.createElement("input");
cfgenvField.name = "updatedDate";
cfgenvField.type = "text";
cfgenvField.value = absolutepath;
form_ref.appendChild(cfgdateField);

form_ref.submit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have the same problem seen here:

[Why can't I submit a dynamically created form in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343974/why-cant-i-submit-a-dynamically-created-form-in-firefox)

it basically says to append it to your document.body before submitting.